# post multi array from razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a list of items in my razor view and  the user can select  (using checkbox)few items (1 or more) and the selected items need to be save in db table .
Im struggling with how to post it in the controller (list/ICollection/[]..)

Some code to explain `

```
 <input type="hidden" value="@item.ApplicationDate" name="ApplicationDate" />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Id" value="@item.Id" /> 
                        //Etc..

     [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> AddToSellList(IList<ReqestWithQA> model ,  /*int[] hiden no prob with simple singel item*/  )
    foreach (var item in model)
                        //etc..
```

I hope its clear

Comment: So you want to post multiple pairs of `Id` & `ApplicationDate`? Can’t you look up the `ApplicationDate` on the server once you have the id?

Comment: Do you want to post it via ajax or using regular submit?

Comment: @poke , yes I could run a query and add all the items from the second table, is it the best approach (I want to attach ApplicationDate & few more items)

Comment: @Alexander ,I think regular submit is the fast one

Comment: It’s certainly better to retrieve the information on the server than to expect the client to pass the information on. After all, you cannot trust the client to pass the correct data. They could completely change all the information that is associated with an item. So you should have to check that data on the server side anyway. And in that case, you can also reduce the request size and not pass that data and only retrieve it on the server.

Comment: @poke Like this >  var FinfQ = await _context.Quetta.Where(a => hiden.Contains(a.Id)).ToArrayAsync();

               foreach (var item in hiden)

Comment: Yeah, for example. Just pass an int array in the form, and then use those ids to fetch the actual objects.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to to have check boxes?

You can go with Select List and make it 'multiple' -> you will get a post then with an array with Key : Value of the options.